# Error Reading PCM file while Written by FFmpeg.exe utility simultaneously in c#

Tags: ffmpeg, c#-4.0, binary-data, pcm

when i run the Ffmpeg.exe utility to convert the live stream to PCM format. Then at the same time I try to read the binary stream I got the error as below.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngh0c.png)

below is the code snippet. as I am using N-audio to convert the stream into Wav format.
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1351j.png)